# TCPDF CodeIgniter Integration won't work

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, tcpdf

I want to integrate codeigniter so I download codeigniter from its official site and place tcpdf folder to CodeIgniter-3.0.6\application\libraries this directory. I create a file named pdf.php in the same directory and put these code.

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/tcpdf/tcpdf.php';

class Pdf extends TCPDF
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

After that I create a file named c_test.php and place it to my controller folder with these code.

```
class pdfexample extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {   
        parent::__construct();  
    } 
    function index()  { 
        $this->load->library('Pdf'); 
        $pdf = new Pdf('P', 'mm', 'A4', true, 'UTF-8', false); 
        $pdf->SetTitle('Pdf Example'); 
        $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(30); 
        $pdf->SetTopMargin(20);
        $pdf->setFooterMargin(20); 
        $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true);
        $pdf->SetAuthor('Author'); 
        $pdf->SetDisplayMode('real', 'default');
        $pdf->Write(5, 'CodeIgniter TCPDF Integration'); 
        ob_clean();
        $pdf->Output('pdfexample.pdf', 'I');
    } 
}
```

But unfortunately my output show's 404 page not found. What should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Put your **TCPDF** folder into the **application/third_party/**

Now create one library into **appliocation/library** and put your code like below.

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once APPPATH."/third_party/tcpdf/tcpdf.php";

class Pdf extends TCPDF {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

and your controller code same as you have written.

Comment: I replace my pdf.php file with above code and follow the procedure but it won't work.

Comment: what's the error you are getting ? also check your browser console log..

Comment: I got 404 page not found